# LightSwitch: How to change the display text in Details Modal Picker

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using Lightswitch 2013 Html Client.

On my screen I have Details Modal Picker which gives all Actions(a business entity). First of all I changed the Summary property into a Rows Layout to enforce the Modal Picker only show the field I want to, but once I selected the Action I wanted (the modal picker display the field I specified in the Screen Designer), the modal picker shows the summary field!! I dont know how to make this display field change into the same field as shown in the selection mode (which I change in the Screen Designer).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is go to your data source and double click on your table you want to change. When the table loads and you can see all the rows/relationships etc, you will see 3 options below the table (Server, Desktop Client and HTML Client). If you click on HTML Client, then in the properties window located usually on the bottom right hand corner, you should see Summary Property. This is where you change it.